Custom Fail2ban Regex not working
Using the regex filter below:
[Definition]

failregex = ^.*Priority: 0

ignoreregex =


Fail2ban does not detect any of these log entries below.

Mon Apr 1 21:11:29 2024 [] [1:1000002:1] SSH attempt [] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 192.x.x.x:58867 -> 192.168.x.x:22

Mon Apr 1 21:11:29 2024 [] [1:1000002:1] SSH attempt [] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 192.x.x.x:58914 -> 192.168.x.x:22


But this same regex filter above, accurately detects the log lines below in Fail2ban and the only difference in the log entries is the date format.

03/26-10:57:44.146011 [] [1:1000002:1] SSH attempt [] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 192.x.x.x:58867 -> 192.168.x.x:22

03/26-11:23:52.317989 [] [1:1000002:1] SSH attempt [] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 192.x.x.x:58914 -> 192.168.x.x:22


I need guidance as i really do not have indepth knowledge on regex.


welcome, did you used the built in tools or chatgpt? what research did you already? For Ssh there is an already well known working rule? please be more specific as in the current point of view it is not very clear to me what you want to solve. Remember that this site is only for Businesses Administrator while the environment must be also in a Business

Thank you. The issue has been resolved with this regex filter - Priority: 0.*

please add this as an answer to your own question and accept it 24h later please
